# Стиль javaFX menuItem

Tags: java, css, javafx, menu, style

Подскажите, как исправить такую проблему через css. Нужно чтобы при наведении на название урока, цвет основного элемента был не синим а тем, который ему задала я изначально?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Может цвет надо установить для .menu:focused или selected?

Comment: Попробуйте menu-bar:showing. Если не получится, рекомендую запустить проект с агентом scenicView, он покажет какие стили в какой момент применяются для элемента.